# Proper handling of API form input in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on an API in express, and I wanted to ask if there's a better way to deal with user input. I use Express 4 and [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/), and use Sequelize for the validation. However, my creating route kinda looks like this:

```
    app.route('/cards').post(requireAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
        // Input validation
        Card.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            caption: req.body.caption,
            cost: req.body.cost,
            tier: req.body.tier,
            cardType: req.body.cardType,
            readyTime: req.body.readyTime,
            attack: req.body.attack,
            health: req.body.health,
            movement: req.body.movement,
            range: req.body.range,
            upkeep: req.body.upkeep,
            canAttack: req.body.canAttack,
            canDefend: req.body.canDefend,
            canMove: req.body.canMove,
            targetable: req.body.targetable,
            description: req.body.description,
            comment: req.body.comment,
            user_id: req.user.id
        })
        .then( function (card) {
            res.send(card);
        })
        .catch( function (e) { next(e); });
    });
```

This works all right, but it leaves a lot to be desired. I omitted the validation of the input, because it's even longer, and this is not even the biggest model in my API.

One problem is obviously that whenever an attribute is not set, the attribute of the model will be set to `null` instead of default or old value. And then there's the problem of re-using this code.

I feel like I'm doing something wrong here, though. I tried to find an `npm` module on this, but only found ones for validation, not for proper putting input into the database.

Perhaps someone has a better, more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the lengthy creation of the record, you could use node's built-in extend function:

```
var extend = require('util')._extend

var newCard = extend({}, req.body);
newCard.user_id = req.user.id;

Card.create(newCard).then(...);
```

And it is possible for define defaults for columns using sequelize when you define your models:

```
sequelize.define('modelName', {
  columnA: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: true
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: Though `.extend` seems to have been removed in current versions of node, and I think `.inherits` is now doing the same job.